# How to redirect one page to another page in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, npm-install

> App.js

This is the event handling button click:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);


handleClick(e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.history.push('/HomePage');
  }


<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Navigate </button>
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

I installed this using: `npm install prop-types --save`

It's not working.

Comment: have you installed react-router????

Comment: Yes i did 'npm install --save react-router' @pageNotfoUnd

Comment: this.props.history.push('/HomePage') or can follow <Link/>tag

Answer (score 14):

To verify why is not working you can `console.log()` your props, and you will see that `history` won't appear, so then how you can fix that? Well, it's easy, you have two ways:

## [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC

> Using `withRouter` You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest 's match via the `withRouter` higher-order component. `withRouter` will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```js
props.history.push('/path')
```

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

function App({ history }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.push('/signup')}>
        Signup
      </button>
    </div> 
  );
}

export default withRouter(App)
```

---

**As of `react-router-dom` v6, `Redirect` no longer exists. You must use [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) instead.**

Example replacement for the code below:

```
return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
```

## [**`<Redirect />`**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component (Pre `react-router-dom` v6)

> Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

class Register extends React.Component {
  state = { toDashboard: false }
  
  handleSubmit = (user) => {
    saveUser(user).then(() => this.setState(() => ({ toDashboard: true })));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.toDashboard) {
      return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this help you folks!

Comment: Just adding: if you dont want to add a new history entry, you can also use history.replace()

Answer (score 10):

## JSX

`<Link to="/home">Homepage</Link>`

If you want to use it in jsx. `<Link>` compiles down to `<a>` tag in HTML so just treat it like that

## Programmatically

`this.props.history.push('/home');`

The reason why history is undefined is you might have the main routing page set up wrong

```
// app.js
import { BrowserRouter, Route, } from 'react-router-dom'
import UserList from './path/to/UserListComponent'

class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        ...
        <Route path="/users" component={UserList}/>
        ...
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Do something like this

Answer (score 8):

You have a two way

use `Redirect` from `react-router`:

In your `handleClick` method set a state and check in the render method and if that's `true` Redirect like the following:

```
<Redirect to="/HomePage" />
```

And another way is using `window.location` like the following:

```
window.location = '/HomePage';
```

Comment: don't do window.location. You will lose app state

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Yes I know, but maybe He need just to redirect

Comment: This works perfectly especially when this.props were undefined. I have taken a state variable by default its false on click of a button make it true and on render I have put a condition if the condition is satisfied redirection works !! BOOM!

Answer (score 6):

React Router v6 implements `useNavigate` ([docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)).

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
let navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/myOtherPath');
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but I want to share something, `react-router-dom` has been updated.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App/>} />
    <Route path="/new-page" element={<Home/>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

like `components` to `element` and  `history.push('/home')` to `navigate('/home')`

```
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  navigate('/new-page'{ state: pass-data } )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push('/new-page');
};

return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to new page</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location.href='/'
```

or

```
<button onClick={() => window.location.href='/'}>Home</button>
```